# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found when using request.urlopen()

Tags: python-3.x, downloading-website-files

I was following a tutorial and when using `request.urlopen(url)` I get an error, I have tried checking the URL
(https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/PH/XPHS/JFC/historical-prices/download?MOD_VIEW=page&num_rows=150&range_days=150&startDate=06/01/2020&endDate=07/05/2020)
and it's fine.

Here is my code:

```
from urllib import request
import datetime

def download_stock_from_day_until_today(stock_code, start_date):
    current_day = datetime.date.today()
    formatted_current_day = datetime.date.strftime(current_day, "%m/%d/%Y") #formats today's date for links
    #formatted url
    url = "https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/PH/XPHS/"+ stock_code +"/historical-prices/download?MOD_VIEW=page&num_rows=150&range_days=150&startDate="+ start_date +"&endDate=" + formatted_current_day

    print(url)

    response = request.urlopen(url) #requests the csv file
    csv = response.read() #reads the csv file
    csv_str = str(csv)
    lines = csv_str.split("\\n")
    dest_url = r'asd.csv'
    fx = open(dest_url, "w")
    for line in lines:
        fx.write(line + "\n")
    fx.close()

download_stock_from_day_until_today("JFC", "06/01/2020")
```

and the error I get in the console is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lathrix/PycharmProject/StockExcelDownloader/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    download_stock_from_day_until_today("JFC", "06/01/2020")
  File "C:/Users/Lathrix/PycharmProject/StockExcelDownloader/main.py", line 12, in download_stock_from_day_until_today
    response = request.urlopen(url) #requests the csv file
  File "C:\Users\Lathrix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Lathrix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Lathrix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\Lathrix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Lathrix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Lathrix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like wsj.com does not like urllib's User-Agent.
With the line

```
response = request.urlopen(request.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}))
```

your code works correctly

Comment: How do you know that the website doesn't work with it? is there any work around with this?

Comment: @lathrix I ran your code and saw that it prints correct url, then I tried to urlopen just www.wsj,com and got 404 error. From browser it works, so I suspected user-agent header. The workaround is in my answer. Just  replace your line 12 with the one that I provided.